# "Missing extra locale data" error even after registerLocaleData() being called

Tags: angular, internationalization

In my project, I have an error when using DatePipe that says "Error: Missing extra locale data for the locale "fr". Use "registerLocaleData" to load new data. See the "I18n guide" on angular.io to know more."

I isolated my problem in the following stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezdf3h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

*For info, the call to getLocaleExtraDayPeriodRules('fr') in HelloComponents is intented to replace the use to DatePipe (it triggers the call to checkFullData in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/737506e79cbda87d8545a663bdd618a884c2e60e/packages/common/src/i18n/locale_data_api.ts#L510)*

I have provided the LOCALE_ID and called registerLocaleData() but it doesn't seem to work

I think I am missing something but can't find what :-/

Comment: You are using language **fr** for which country?

Comment: @surendrakumar France

Comment: For France use 'fr-FR'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to import.

You need to pass the country with language **fr**.

**Example:**  'fr-CA'/'fr-US'

```
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeFrExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr';
import { registerLocaleData, DecimalPipe, CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common';
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-CA', localeFrExtra);
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed there was a third parameter, and I totally missed the extra folder in android sources 